# How to split the Rest API response fields into KIE Workbench runtime variables

Tags: java, rest, api, kie-workbench, kie-server

Im using KIE Workbench-6.5.0 and KIE server-6.5.0

here im created the Repository and Project. In Business process section i create the new bpmn flow with Rest Service Node. In this Rest service node in added the Rest API URL, Method, Content & Content Type. And store the API response in another KIE Wb variable as Object. Im getting the API response below like this and stored into KIE-wb variable "bpmResponse".

```
{
    "user":{
        "userName":"visnu",
        "age":"26",
    },
    "address":{
        "address":"Anna Nagar",
        "city":"Chennai",
        "state":"TN"
    }
}
```

Here i want to store the "user" object to kie-wb variable "userObj" and "address" object o kie-wb variable "addressObj".

How can i do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above issue.

I stored the API response to "bpmResponse" as Json String. 
1. I check the "bpmResponse" instance type
2. Then i convert json string to corresponding object using gson, now i got the splitted objects from the response.

Thanks.

Comment: How have you done the check, split and convert in the KIE Workbench UI? Is there a way in the UI to mark the variable, which holds the JSON string response as a JSON object, and the Workbench to parse it automatically for you? I am trying to do this, but I get ClassCastExceptions.